# initialised or initialized which one is correct spelling?

Tags: etymology, orthography, north-american-english, ise-ize, insular-english

I have often seen ***initialised*** in lots of text, but when I want to write it in Microsoft office word, it says it was misspelled and it should be ***initialized*** instead of ***initialised***.

so here is my question:

> Which one of them is the correct spelling?

and if both of them are correct, when I should use one or the other? Is there any rule regarding this?

Additional note: when I was writing this post, it would give me a spelling error notice each time I wrote ***initialised***.

Comment: There might be an option to select British spelling in your operating system or word processor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The variant of *initialize* with an *s* is the British spelling; the one with a *z* is standard American.

See [here.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/initialize)

If you’re British, you’re likely to use the *s* variant. If you’re an American (like me), you’ll use the *z* variant.

Incidentally, many words that replace a *z* with an *s* tend to be British spelling, like [“realise.”](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/realize) [American variant=realize]

Comment: Please do not answer duplicates; mark them as such. [It’s more complex than this in many ways](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2011/03/28/ize-or-ise/): “In British English, it doesn’t matter which spelling convention is chosen: neither is right or wrong, and neither is ‘more right’ than the other.” Thus spake Oxford.

Comment: @tchrist It may not matter which “spelling convention” is chosen, and one spelling might not be more correct than the other, but the fact remains that -ise spellings aren’t standard in American English and are generally used in British English.

Comment: Did you read the article? Why are you answering duplicates?

Comment: @tchrist I did read the article, actually. I’ve read it before you posted it as well. And I did not know that this was a duplicate question until you mentioned it.

Comment: Wait, wait. Its the other way around. Its you, Americans, who replaces `s` with an `z`.